# BCMath - imitate calculator or excel

Tags: php, bcmath

I'm working with decimal values that can have more decimal digits than the float type, so I have to use bcmath functions.
My problem is that standard calculators like in Windows, Android or PHP operators can calculate terms like a / b * b = a

Is there a way to get the same result with BCMath (as the floating point version) but don't lose precision if needed?

```
$a = '897.8';
$b = '1046.15';

$c = bcdiv($a, $b, 15);

$d = bcmul($c, $b, 15);

print "C:".$c."\n";
print "D:".$d."\n";

print 897.8 / 1046.15 * 1046.15. "\n";

$e = 897.8 / 1046.15;
print $e. "\n";
print $e * 1046.15;
```

Output:

```
C:0.858194331596807
D:897.799999999999643
897.8
0.85819433159681
897.8
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. It's like if you do `1 / 3 * 3` in decimal. `1/3` is `0.333333...`. When you multiply that, you get `0.999999....`

Comment: @Barmar Correct, but if you enter 1 / 3 * 3  into PHP arithmetic or a calculator, you will get 1. So there must be rounding.

Comment: Yes. But when you use `bcmath` and specify a precision, you get that level of detail.